# Using checkedValue binding with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to make use of the checkedValue binding introduced in knockout version 3, with radio buttons , but am not getting the behavior I expect.

Here's an example: (the viewModel has two properties; `list` is an array; `checkedVal` is an observable)

```
<div data-bind="foreach:list">
    <input type="radio" data-bind="
        checkedValue: {
            data: $data,
            index: $index(),
        },
        checked: $parent.checkedVal
    "/>
    <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fJ5Pz/1/)

I expect the radio buttons to behave normally, and checkedVal to be an object containing the data and index.  checkedVal is as I expect, but the radio buttons don't select.  Oddly, in my actual code the behavior is inconsistent; sometimes the radio butttons work and sometimes they don't, but it consistently doesn't work in the fiddle, as far as I can see.

Is this a bug, or am I misunderstanding how this should be working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that this issue has been resolved in newer versions of KO.  As of version 3.2 I'm no longer seeing this behavior mentioned in my original question.

Here's a [working JSFiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/Retsam19/fJ5Pz/7/), identical to the original, except with KO updated to 3.2 .

Answer (score 1):

Your `checkedValue` binding becomes a function as follows:

```
function () {
    return {
        data: $data,
        index: $index(),
    };
}
```

Each time the `checked` binding updates, it calls this function to get the value. But the function always returns a new object. Even though the objects contains the same data, Knockout doesn't see them as the same.

You can solve this by making the value a string.

```
    <input type="radio" data-bind="
        checkedValue: JSON.stringify({
            data: $data,
            index: $index(),
        }),
        checked: $parent.checkedVal
    "/>
```

Or by binding to a consistent value.

```
    <input type="radio" data-bind="
        checkedValue: $data,
        checked: $parent.checkedVal
    "/>
```

EDIT:

You can use a custom binding that follows the same pattern as `checked`, but allows for a comparison function.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.radioChecked = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "click", function() {
            if (element.checked) {
                var observable = valueAccessor(), 
                    checkedValue =  allBindings.get('checkedValue');
                observable(checkedValue);
            }
        });
    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        var modelValue = valueAccessor()(), 
            checkedValue =  allBindings.get('checkedValue'), 
            comparer = allBindings.get('checkedComparer');
        element.checked = comparer(modelValue, checkedValue);
    }
};
```

Then objects can be compared by contents.

```
this.itemCompare = function(a, b) {
    return JSON.stringify(a) == JSON.stringify(b);
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mbest/Q4LSQ/

Comment: If this is true, then I don't see the point of checkedValue; the first example certainly would have worked with just 'value', and I think the second would as well.

Comment: You might be interested in the custom binding I added that can be used instead of `checked` and supports a comparison function.